# How to use SQL multiplication from other table MS Access in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I want to use SQL multiplication from other table MS access in VB.NET

```
SELECT EC.EMPID,E.NAME,EC.SKILL/(select MIN(MINSKILL.SKILL) 
     FROM tblEmployeeCriteria MINSKILL)*100 as SKILL 
FROM tblEmployeeCriteria EC 
INNER JOIN tblemployee E ON EC.EMPID = E.EMPID
```

tblemployee

| EMPID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran |
| 10046 | Ponisan |
| 10085 | Vanu |

tblEmployeeCriteria

| EMPID | SKILL |
| --- | --- |
| 10037 | 90 |
| 10046 | 80 |
| 10085 | 50 |

tblWeightingCriteria

| ID | WCSKILL | WCEXPERIENCE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 81 | 71 |

Result from SQL now :

| EMPID | NAME | SKILL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran | 180 |
| 10046 | Ponisan | 170 |
| 10085 | Vanu | 100 |

EXAMPLE VALUE SKILL FROM TAMENDRAN : 90/50*100=180

Desired Result :

| EMPID | NAME | SKILL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10037 | Tamendran | 145.80 |
| 10046 | Ponisan | 137.70 |
| 10085 | Vanu | 81 |

EXAMPLE VALUE SKILL FROM TAMENDRAN : 90/50*100 * 81/100=145.80

Comment: Emulate what I did for your original question: why don't you simply add `*(select WCSKILL/100 from tblWeightingCriteria)`; assuming there is only one row in this table (if not make sure that you have the appropriate WHERE condition to reduce to the criteria row you are interested in)

Comment: @tinazmu , Your answer went perfectly. Please you answer as an answer so I can mark your answer

Comment: Hi @user18, it is really a duplicate of your previous question, and we can leave it as is so that the site is clean

Comment: @tinazmu , Actually there is a little different because there is the addition of another table

Comment: @user18 Be careful that it doesn't do integer arithmetic where you don't intend it, as that will make the divisions appear to give the wrong result: [Integer division in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3443672/1115360).

Comment: @tinazmu , I have a recent post maybe you can help me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76209949/how-to-create-a-descending-sql-for-the-column-total-and-add-the-column-rank?noredirect=1#comment134395365_76209949)

Comment: @AndrewMorton , Thank you for your suggestion, but I have calculated the value so the value is in accordance with the actual calculation